# Is there a way to bind a couple of instances to many different keys in Guice?

Tags: java, collections, guava, guice

We need to create some mapping between many types of some object, described with enum values:

```
public enum ObjectType {
Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4,Type5...TypeN
}
```

... and

1. several instances of strategies to use for these types
2. or, for example, boolean values which relate to the mentioned ObjectTypes

A MapBinder from Guice can be used for this purpose, along with a standart HashMap, as well as some complex map from google collections.

What I want is to find something that suits that "low-density" structure of the "values" of this match. I would like to see something like

```
binder.addBinding(ObjectType.Type1,ObjectType.Type2...ObjectType.Type6).toInstance(Boolean.TRUE)
or
binder.addBinding(ObjectType.Type1,ObjectType.Type2...ObjectType.Type6).toInstance(new SomeStrategyForFirstSixObjectType())
```

Any advice?

Comment: Try [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) (and [range method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#range%28E,%20E%29)) + [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) + simple for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to loop across the values:

```
for (ObjectType type : ObjectType.values()) {
  // Assumes you've created a binding annotation @YourAnnotation(ObjectType) along
  // with an implementation called YourAnnotationImpl.
  bind(Boolean.class)
      .annotatedWith(new YourAnnotationImpl(type))
      .toInstance(Boolean.TRUE));

  // Now you can inject "@YourAnnotation(Type1) Boolean yourValue" and so on.
}
```

However, though it may make sense for some purposes, you may not want to have separate Boolean bindings for every value in Guice—especially when binding multiple related values. Instead you might consider gathering everything together into a `TypeConfiguration` (for instance), which you could bind per-type as above, and replace with a `FakeTypeConfiguration` in tests.

You could also gather everything together and bind it in a `Map`:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<ObjectType, Boolean>> {})
    .toInstance(ImmutableMaps.<ObjectType, Boolean>newBuilder()
        .add(Type1, TRUE)
        .add(Type2, TRUE)
        // [snip, you could replace with a for-loop or pre-built map]
        .build());

// Now you can inject "Map<ObjectType, Boolean>".
```